# How to make Foundation 5 Reveal Popup responsive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, zurb-foundation

I am using Foundation’s latest version Foundation 5, I want to use Reveal Popup in my project, I tried to implementing using following code and `.js` files.

It’s working fine in Large displays like Laptop and tablets, but when I try to open my page in small devices like mobile then it’s not showing properly I have to travel right and left in my mobile screen to see entire popup.

- Included CSS

  `<link href="../../Content/foundation/css/foundation.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="../../Content/foundation/css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`
- HTML part

[image: HTML Part]

[image: Included Script]

Please help me or suggest me if I missed anything in above code.

- image 2
  [image: image2]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the foundation's in-built grid classes `large-10 small-10 medium-10`

```
<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal large-10 small-10 medium-10 columns" data-reveal>
  <h2>Popup title.</h2>
  <p class="lead">Your couch.  It is mine.</p>
  <p>Im a cool paragraph that lives inside of an even cooler modal. Wins</p>
  <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

**And you have to remove this line of css :**

```
.reveal-modal {
  width: 100vw; //remove this line from your css
}
```

Comment: Updated answer , remove that line

Answer (score 0):

In `_reveal.scss` edit the `@media #{$small-only}` section.

add the line `width: 90vw;`

It should look like this when you are done:

```
@media #{$small-only} {
  min-height:100vh;
  width: 90vw;
}
```

You can also remove the line `min-height:100vh;` if you do not want the modal to vertically fill the screen on mobile devices.

This solution does not require use of grid columns.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers will work, sort of. This is actually due to foundation no longer applying box-sizing:border-box to all elements across the board.  It is adding the padding to the overall reveal 100% width, which pushes it outside the body.

```
.reveal-modal {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    min-height:0 /* If you want to remove the full viewport height effect */
}
```